# How to get record form a different table based on a value from first table with linq expression?

Tags: c#, linq

[I am not sure on linq for this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLH0e.png)How to get record from other table based on a value from first table with linq expression.

```
public IQueryable GetAllMeeting()
        {
            var allMeeting = from xx in _dbContext.tbl_Meeting
                             select new Meeting
                             {
                                 Meeting_Attendee_Id = xx.Attendees,
                                 Meeting_Agenda = xx.Agenda,
                                 Meeting_Date = xx.Date,
                                 Id = xx.Id,
                                 Meeting_Subject = xx.Subject,
                                 CreatedById = xx.Created_By
                             };
            var meetingCreatedBy = _dbContext.tbl_User.SingleOrDefault(x=>x.Id == allMeeting.Creaated)
            return allMeeting;  // not sure if same thing can be done while fatching allMeetings or need to do a separate?
        }
```

Comment: what are you doing with `meetingCreatedBy` ?

Comment: @Valkyrie that is something I need to return to UI, it should have meeting created by as well...I am even not sure on linq operation I am doing correct or not.

Comment: What you have done technically can be done. but not sure it's a best practice. you might be able to get this using join (but I don't know your condition or data structure). The issue is that you are returning IQueryable and a Materialized `meetingCreatedBy `. this issue aside, If you wish to return `meetingCreatedBy` with `allMeeting` you need to assign the returned value of `meetingCreatedBy` to an object from `allMeeting` meaning for example: `allMeeting.CreatedBy = meetingCreatedBy;` then return `allMeeting' all together. although u should change IQueryable.

Comment: @Valkyrie what I should chage IQuerable to? List<>

Comment: It depends on your return data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use let clause  See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/let-clause)

```
public IQueryable GetAllMeeting()
        {
            var allMeeting = from xx in _dbContext.tbl_Meeting
                    let meetingCreatedBy = _dbContext.tbl_User.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Id == xx.CreatedById)
                             select new Meeting
                             {
                                 Meeting_Attendee_Id = xx.Attendees,
                                 Meeting_Agenda = xx.Agenda,
                                 Meeting_Date = xx.Date,
                                 Id = xx.Id,
                                 Meeting_Subject = xx.Subject,
                                 CreatedById = xx.Created_By,

                                 CreatedBy = meetingCreatedBy !=null ? meetingCreatedBy.Name : "" //Or whatever property/column you have for displaying the name
                             };
              return allMeeting;
        }
```

Note: If these two tables are related with each other  and the relationships are properly defined i.e. Created_By of table tbl_Meeting is connected with Id of tbl_User  .You can simply use the navigation property to retrieve  the user who created the meeting (i.e. xx.tbl_User.Name) . I would strongly recommend reading [navigation properties and relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/relationships)

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform join operation (probably left join) between two entities. Also add the required property inside model objec and return the value.